# Java UDP - Packet Send Problem

Tags: java, network-programming

Everytime I try to send a UDP packet to an address I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:625)
    at services.servicetypes.network.host.Server_UDP_Thread_Monitor.send(Server_UDP_Thread_Monitor.java:84)
```

Which points directly to the socket send function - this.socket.send(packet);

After placing a break point on my datagram packet I get the following info:

```
packet  DatagramPacket  java.net.DatagramPacket@52c4c57 
byte[]  #1248(length=16)    
offset  int 0   
length  int 16  
bufLength   int 16  
address Inet4Address    /192.168.0.101  
Static          
Inherited   
port    int 3889
```

I'm not clear on why this is occuring, if anyone could shed any light on the problem that would be great. My inital thoughts were perhaps one of the datagram packet elements was empty.

(Basic source)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(byteOut);

// Game type
out.writeInt(1);

// Client
out.writeInt(gamerToSend.getClientID());

// Position
out.writeFloat(gamerToSend.getX());
out.writeFloat(gamerToSend.getY());


DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket
(
  byteOut.toByteArray(),
  byteOut.size(),
  gamerToSend.getInetAddress(),
  3887
);

this.socket.send(packet);

byteOut.close();
out.close();
```

INetAddress info: (Ip is correctly displaying destination machine)

```
address Inet4Address    /192.168.0.101  /192.168.0.101  
Static      
INADDRSZ    int 4   4   
serialVersionUID    long    3286316764910316507 3286316764910316507 
loopback    int 2130706433  2130706433  
IPv4    int 1   1   
IPv6    int 2   2   
preferIPv6Address   boolean false   false   
nameService InetAddress$1   java.net.InetAddress$1@5bf0cf51 java.net.InetAddress$1@5bf0cf51 
serialVersionUID    long    3286316764910316507 3286316764910316507 
addressCache    InetAddress$Cache   java.net.InetAddress$Cache@1ebafdff java.net.InetAddress$Cache@1ebafdff 
negativeCache   InetAddress$Cache   java.net.InetAddress$Cache@679801c  java.net.InetAddress$Cache@679801c  
addressCacheInit    boolean true    true    
unknown_array   InetAddress[]   #1266(length=1) #1266(length=1) 
impl    Inet6AddressImpl    java.net.Inet6AddressImpl@12c9b196  java.net.Inet6AddressImpl@12c9b196  
lookupTable HashMap "size = 0"  "size = 0"  
$assertionsDisabled boolean true    true    
Inherited               
hostName                
address int -1062731675 -1062731675 
family  int 2   2   
canonicalHostName               
caport  int 3889    3889
```

Server source
http://pastebin.com/JCdjhFQM

Comment: You need to post your code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Apologies, forgot, source code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help.

It appears the InetAddress is corrupted somewhere as manually setting it to the remote machine like so:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.101");
```

Works perfectly fine, so I have more debugging to do, but thats the problem.

Again thanks for the assist!

Comment: Make sure to accept your own answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it has something to do with using the `DataOutputStream` which is buffered, then passing the underlying `byte[]`.

Try `out.flush()` before creating your packet.

Comment: I've tried, but same error as before.

out.flush();

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket....

Comment: The problem is that obviously, the length isn't matching the byte[] you're passing in. Before your packet, do a `byte[] foo = byteOut.toByteArray();` and pass that in with `foo.length` as the size. Or just compare `byteOut.size()` to that length and see if there's a difference.

Comment: byte[] foo =  byteOut.toByteArray();

System.out.println("1~" + byteOut.size());
System.out.println("2~" + foo.length);

1~16
2~16

No difference...

Comment: You write 16 byte, but your packet has only 13 byte (from the debugging data you posted).

Comment: My bad I added some additional data by mistake. Both now show 16 bytes but the issue remains.

Comment: Got me then. 16 bytes is correct for what you put into the buffer (4 + 4 + 4 + 4). According to the docs, that should work. Unless you're doing something odd creating the InetAddress which I don't know how you would. Or something odd with the socket?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JCdjhFQM < that's the basic code for my server, I've also added the debug output of the InetAddress in my first post.

Comment: Note the other person's answer. Runs fine on my machine as well. What version of java and OS are you on? It's the native library that's puking.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the part you posted. I wrapped your source in an example program, and it works without any problems.

```
package de.fencing_game.paul.examples;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

/**
 */
public class UDPTest {

    private static class Gamer {
        int clientID;
        float x;
        float y;
        InetAddress address;

        public int getClientID() { return clientID; }
        public float getX() { return x; }
        public float getY() { return y; }
        public InetAddress getInetAddress() { return address; }
    }


    private DatagramSocket socket;


    public UDPTest() throws IOException
    {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
    }


    public void sendPackage(Gamer gamerToSend)
        throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(byteOut);

        // Game type
        out.writeInt(1);

        // Client
        out.writeInt(gamerToSend.getClientID());

        // Position
        out.writeFloat(gamerToSend.getX());
        out.writeFloat(gamerToSend.getY());

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket
            (
                byteOut.toByteArray(),
                byteOut.size(),
                gamerToSend.getInetAddress(),
                3887
            );

        this.socket.send(packet);

        byteOut.close();
        out.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] ignored)
        throws IOException
    {
        Gamer g = new Gamer();
        g.address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        UDPTest sender = new UDPTest();
        sender.sendPackage(g);
    }

}
```

What are you doing different?